# When observing .Value, how do I get the value of the child keys?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q" =     {
    id = UDtAJcqsMbNWxwApTh75sEl9DN83;
    la = "";
    na = "Julie Chang";
};
```

This is what the snapshot looks like when observing with .Value. How do I get the "na" value? It would be something like

```
 snapshot.valueForKey("-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q").valueForKey("na")
```

but I have no way of getting the "-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q" value to do so.

I could use .ChildAdded, but it doesn't update for updates of values.

Comment: For catching updates to children, use `.ChildChanged`. To loop over the children, use the `snapshot.children` property: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.

Comment: I need Added and Changed, I was under the impression I needed to use .Value to do so. So an object like the one above may be added and one of the children may be updated. Also your last name sounds like a house in Hogwarts.

Comment: I'm trying to add chat to an app. So a user would create a chat and there would be a reference to the chat's uid to that user and the receiving user. In the list of chats above is the reference. "-KNQ66QDmXXc2E8K-B4Q" is the chatroom and the child is the other user's information. "la" is the last message received that is shown in the list of chats just like how it shows on the iPhones Messages.